# What is an efficient way to load more than a million images for a collectible card game?

Tags: c#, algorithm, architecture, monogame

I'm using C# with MonoGame and I'm wondering what would be an efficient way to load more than a million card images for a collectible card game. More cards would be continuously added in future updates and what not. I'm sure there are some genius ways to go about this which are both elegant and efficient. I'm hoping to obtain some insight on how others would solve this problem.

The cards will all be on a client side application the user downloads. The server will make sure the players are not cheating. I'm trying to figure out what are efficient ways to manage a large amount of card images on the client side regarding the loading and unloading of the cards.

I understand the cards should loaded and shown only when necessary. However, there are points in the game where the user can look through their entire collection. I was thinking with a scrollbar or something along those lines. They can filter their cards based on certain properties of the cards. In this scenario, how would I manage the loading/unloading of the cards in real time to make it seamless and efficient.

Comment: Not all at once - that's the only way.

Comment: You certainly cannot view one million (or more) images at once, so why would you load them at once ?

Comment: is it actually a million pictures or are you just saying that for the effect?

Comment: I'm certain I wouldn't be displaying a million images at once but underneath the hood what is a good way to manage them? Loading the images from the harddrive won't be the fastest but what improvements can I make to make it efficient as possible?

Comment: Not enough detail -- vote to close

Comment: @rotaercz so you actually want to know how to store X images and load some of them efficiently.

Comment: You actually can show million images all at once as long as each is 1x1 pixel (there is even advertisement site based on that). How useful to have 1m small images instead of using sprite-sheet approach I'm not sure...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that is simply showing 1 million pixels at once in a single image. Otherwise, supposing a typical image where intensities are in the range [0, 255], you cannot create more than 256 distinct images given single channel images. And I don't believe you can do anything useful with 1 pixel images either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would NOT load all the images at once. Whether this is an online game or not it would be terribly inefficient to load all of them at once. One way around this would be to put them all into some kind of database and only load the cards needed when they are needed, like when a new hand is dealt, etc. If you are worried about query speeds slowing you game down check out [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/writing-efficient-sql-set-based-speed-phreakery/) detailed article/contest on how to right the fastest queries, as well as [these](http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/) tips.

**As to your edit:**

You could still use a SQL database on a server and run queries to make sure they are not cheating. You don't need to check ALL their cards, just the ones they currently have or are dealing.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an online game.  I'm thinking you'll want to use a database (MySQL, etc.) to store the card information.  Card images would be stored on an FTP for quick access, and their paths would be stored on the database.  Then use queries to access the necessary cards needed for the current screen.

Comment: There is nothing about FTP that is synonymous with "quick access".

Comment: @rotaercz "Image Files"?

Comment: The image files are all the individual card art in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You should not load a million images at once. Only load on demand ...e.g. when a card is dealt, load the image.

I believe you can keep images in a database. That is the most efficient storage and retrieval mechanism. Or you could store as binary data. Short of keeping image data in RAM or SSHD, you won't get much faster.

If your concern is performance, I think you have your priorities wrong. ;)

Comment: The user would have all the card image files on their computer. They would download a client to play the game and connect to a server to play with other people. I would not be directly passing the card images directly from a database/server. The server would only be making sure that the game is fair and no one is cheating.